# Allowing buttons to be clicked if one or more checkbox are clicked

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have in my page two buttons, edit and delete. Edit only should be clicked if one checkbox are clicked, and delete should be clicked if one or more buttons are clicked.

I think my solutions is wrong:

```
<li class="controller {{if editRecord '' 'controller__item--disabled' }}">Edit</li>
<li class="controller {{if destroyRecord '' 'controller__item--disabled'}}">Delete</li>
```

And i'm observing two times model.@each.checked:

```
editRecord: Ember.computed('model.@each.checked', function() {
  let count = 0;
  this.get('model').forEach((item) => {
      if (item.get('checked')) {
        count +=1;
      }
  });

   if (count === 1) return true;
   return false;
});


deleteRecord: Ember.computed('model.@each.checked', function() {
  let count = 0;
  this.get('model').forEach((item) => {
      if (item.get('checked')) {
        count +=1;
      }
  });

   if (count >= 1) return true;
   return false;
});
```

The problem is.. if i have 10 buttons and i need check each one.. this will be unmaintainable..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to render two buttons per record in your model and each of them depends on a property in your model called `checked`, right?

If this is the case, then you just need to use an `{{each}}` handlebar:

```
{{!template.hbs}}
{{#each model as |item|}}
  <li class="controller {{if editRecord '' 'controller__item--disabled' }}">Edit</li>
  <li class="controller {{if destroyRecord '' 'controller__item--disabled'}}">Delete</li>
{{/each}}
```

For each record in your model, this will render those two buttons. Then, in your `*.js` file you can optimize it to this:

```
//controller.js or component.js or route.js
_count: Ember.computed('model.@each.checked', function() {
  let count = 0;
  this.get('model').forEach((item) => {
      if (item.get('checked')) {
        count +=1;
      }
  });
  return count;
});

editRecord: Ember.computed('_count', function() {
  return this.get('_count') === 1 ?  true : false;
});

deleteRecord: Ember.computed('_count', function() {
  return this.get('_count') >= 1 ? true : false;
});
```

with this `_count` you just count the `checked` values one time per change and the rest of computed properties only depend on its result.

Comment: This is way overkill, Ember provides builtins for those things. Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Ember provides tools to make such tasks easy:

```
// In your component or controller
checkedModels: Ember.computed.filterBy('model', 'checked'),
editRecord: Ember.computed.equal('checkedModels.length', 1),
deleteRecord: Ember.computed.gte('checkedModels.length', 1)
```

This uses ember [shortcuts](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html) to define:

- `checkedModels` to be an array with only checked models.
- `editRecord` to be true when there is exactly one checked model.
- `deleteRecord` to be true when there is one or more checked model.

As a sidenote, in your template, I would recommend using the `<button>` html element for buttons. Better compatibility, better semantic, and has a `disabled` attribute you can use to disable it properly:

```
<li class="controller"><button disabled={{unless editRecord true}}>Edit</button></li>
<li class="controller><button disabled={{unless deleteRecord true}}>Delete</button></li>
```